# Callback из WebView в Java

Tags: javascript, java, android

Как из JS кода в WebView можно вызвать Java функцию / listener с параметрами?

Мне это нужно для рекапчи. Код JS, нужное место обозначено комментарием:

```
 // recaptcha onload callback
        var recaptchaCallback = function (response) {
            // дальше как передать переменную response в Java?
        }

        var onloadCallbackRecaptcha = function () {
            window.renderedReCaptcha = grecaptcha.render ($("#recaptcha")[0], {
                theme: 'light',
                sitekey: '6LewbRgTAAAAAPv5S8k2ATMv2kiRsKi_lxRLr41R',
                callback: recaptchaCallback
            })
        }
```

Необходима поддержка 15 API